# How to save picture boxplot seaborn

Tags: python, boxplot, seaborn

I create a boxplot as bellow

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
```

& try to save

```
sns.boxplot.savefig('ax.png')
```

or

```
ax.savefig('ax.png')
```

but

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

It's surprisely, beacause it's correct for lmplot etc....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to first generate the matplotlib figure and axes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Then do all the plotting you need with seaborn, specifying the axes to use, e.g.

```
sns.boxplot('A', 'B', data=your_dataframe, ax=ax)
```

And finally save in the usual way

```
plt.savefig('your_figure.png')
```

Answer (score 5):

`lmplot` does not return an `AxesSubplot` instance, `boxplot` does. You can get the figure `ax` belongs to and then `savefig` it:

```
ax.get_figure().savefig('ax.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sns.plt` to save images.

```
sns.plt.clf()
sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
sns.plt.savefig('ax.png')
```